# jQuery slideable divs with floated images how to make the right size

Tags: jquery

I am relatively new to using jQuery and I have a problem with creating some sliding tabs to work with images that are floated inside.

http://www.dur.ac.uk/malachi.soord/jin/

The above page demonstrates the problem I am facing - click on the about tab and you will notice that the image that is inside is floated to the right - which I know is not taken into consideration when jQuery is calculates the height of each div tab with:

```
$("#content > div").each (function() {
        $(this).css("height", $(this).height());
});
```

Is there a work around which could be used to allow me to take this into consideration? or is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to achieving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a height on that div. The height will auto format. I tested this on your site by editing your html with firebug.